# Why ctypes sizeof treats c_ubyte*1 and c_char*1 in the structure differently?

Tags: python, ctypes

When I define a ctypes structure with `c_char` array as a field I can't get the size of that field, but if I switch to `c_ubyte` array I can. My understanding is that in the following example Python treats `bar2` as a pointer (char*), but not `bar1`. I'd appreciate if someone can explain the logic behind that.

```
import ctypes
class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ('bar1', ctypes.c_ubyte*1),
                 ('bar2', ctypes.c_char*1) ]
foo = Foo()
for f,t in foo._fields_:
    print t

print ctypes.sizeof(foo.bar1)
print ctypes.sizeof(foo.bar2)
```

and this is the output:

```
<class '__main__.c_ubyte_Array_1'>
<class '__main__.c_char_Array_1'>
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print ctypes.sizeof(foo.bar2)
TypeError: this type has no size
```

Comment: I suspect it has something to do how C treats a char and arrays of char differently than Python does where both are sequences. Just use `ctypes.c_byte` instead of `ctypes.c_char` and `foo.bar2` will have a size.

Comment: @martineau right, I'm using `ctypes.c_ubyte` instead. Run into that issue while trying to define `sockaddr_in` according to standard `char    sin_zero[8]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`foo.bar1` is indeed a ctypes array of 1 ubyte, but `foo.bar2` is a string made out of what is in the array, considered as a null-terminated C string.  It's clearer if you make longer arrays, say of length 5: if they contain for example the character 'A' repeated, then `foo.bar1` will read as

```
<__main__.c_ubyte_Array_5 object at 0xf7551df4>
```

whereas `foo.bar2` will read as

```
"AAAAA"
```

which is a normal Python string.  This is a special case for the `c_char` type.  Indeed, it's annoying because there is no clean way to write this value `"AAAAA"` into `bar2` in the first place...

Comment: So you're saying `foo.bar2` gets auto converted to Python string. That's explains it. I can use `len(foo.bar2)` instead.

An interesting observation is that `a = ctypes.c_char*5` does not follow this behavior.

    class Foo(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [ ('bar', ctypes.c_char*5) ]
    foo = Foo("12345")`

get converted to a string without an error, while `a = ctypes.c_char*5` is treated as a true char array:

    a = (ctypes.c_char*5)("12345")

fails with `TypeError: one character string expected`. I wonder if it's a bug or a feature of ctypes.

Comment: I could drop in an ad for cffi at this point: it's meant as a simpler alternative to ctypes. http://cffi.readthedocs.org/